# SSRS - Default parameter as max date in database - MDX

Tags: sql, reporting-services, parameters, mdx

I know how to set max date in database as default parameter in normal query. In new dataset I wrote this: 
`ISNULL(MAX(C0_TIME), DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, GETDATE()), 0)) AS END` and used it in default parameter settings.

But how to get the same effect by using MDX? What should I use/write?

Thanks for help ;)

Comment: Which value do you want to use as the default value? The first year available in the cube? How is your period hierarchy called and how is it structured?

Comment: I use 2 parameters - first for start date and second for end date. Default end date is the last: year,quarter and month available in the cube. There's a screenshot of this structure: http://imgur.com/kBAacYS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this solution with @FrankPl help.
In new dataset I wrote in QueryDesigner:
`WITH MEMBER [Measures].[ParameterValue] AS Tail([Czas].[Czas].Members).Item(0).Item(0).UNIQUENAME SELECT {[Measures].[ParameterValue]} ON COLUMNS , [Czas].[Czas].LastChild ON ROWS FROM [PM01]`.
Then I got one row with `ParameterValue` which gave me the name of last year,quarter&month in the cube. I used it as `Default Value` in my EndData parameter which is connected with another Dataset. And this Dataset returns me appropriate measures which I using to do a report.

Answer (score 1):

```
Tail([Czas].[Czas].Members).Item(0).Item(0)
```

should give you the last month, as it is the last member of your `Czas` hierarchy. `Tail` returns a subset containing the tuple of a set, the first `Item(0)` returns the first and only tuple, and the second returns the first and only member.

In case you want to have the last year, just change the set from which you take the tail, e. g. to `[Czas].[Czas].[Rok].Members`, using the `Rok` level.

To get all months within the last year of the cube, you could use the range operator `:` with `null` as the second element, which means "to the end on the same level":

```
Tail([Czas].[Czas].[Rok].Members).Item(0).Item(0).FirstChild().FirstChild() : null
```

would return all months in the last year (`Rok`). Of course, you can also explicitly state the end member:

```
Tail([Czas].[Czas].[Rok].Members).Item(0).Item(0).FirstChild().FirstChild() : Tail([Czas].[Czas].Members).Item(0).Item(0)
```

Comment: Ok, it works, but only in Query Designer --> Czas as a Dimension & Hierarchy, MDX as an Operator and e.g. Tail([Czas].[Czas].Members).Item(0).Item(0) as a Filter Expression. But how to change it by using Range (Inclusive)? The only way I see is to change it in panel Report Data -> Parameters -> EndDate -> Default Value. And when I pasted your code into that box, it didn't work.

Comment: @Monic I do not understand from your question which range you want to use. Could you please clarify?

Comment: Right. Now I see, I didn't say anything about StartDate.
My StartDate is date of first month (always January) in current year.
My EndDate is date of last month in current year, which is available in the cube OR first month (January) if the last avaible date in my cube is the December of previous year.
That's all what I want to use im my filtr report.

Comment: And I saw, that when I choose (in QueryDesigner) 'Range (Inclusive)' in column called 'Operator' and choose anything in 'Filter Expression', then I'll have 2 new parameters: FromCzasCzas & To CzasCzas. And I can change their default value.

Comment: @Monic I extended my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your time ;) But I still don't know where should I use your code. If I wrote it in QueryDesigner -->Dimension: Czas--> Operator: MDX, I'll give an error: http://imgur.com/jygAYgV.
And then I cannot use parameters even if it works.

Comment: @Monic Sorry, I am not an Reporting Services expert. I only can tell you how to work with MDX.

Comment: Ok, so maybe I will find solution with your clues. :) Please tell me, is it necessary to write ".Item(0)"? If I don't write it, I'll have the same result. And second: I read that I can use function LastChild instead of Tail(). Is it big difference between them?

Comment: This depends on what you have: `LastChild`, `FirstChild` work on a member, returning a member, while `Tail` works on a set and returns a set. `Tail` works on the set returned by `Members`. If you have the last year available, then `LastChild` would be the better choice.  SSAS does an automatic type conversion from member to tuple or set in a context where it expects a tuple or set, but not vice versa; this means if you have a set where you need a member, you need the `.Item(0).Item(0)`. The first extracts the first tuple from the set, and the second extracts the first member from the tuple.

Comment: Finally :D I've done such thing:
    
`WITH MEMBER [Measures].[ParameterValue] AS Tail([Czas].[Czas].Members).Item(0).Item(0).UNIQUENAME 
SELECT {[Measures].[ParameterValue]} ON COLUMNS ,  [Czas].[Czas].LastChild ON ROWS FROM [PM01]`
    
And it works through setting `[ParameterValue]` as `Default value` in parameter. But I have one question more. Is it correct when it comes to syntax MDX?

Comment: @Monic The statement as you put it into your comment is valid MDX on the first view. (You could easily check that by running it.) However, I am not sure it delivers what you want, as the `ParameterValue` measure delivers the name of last year as output, not any data values. And it shows this, independent of what you put into the rows. Probably, you would need a different syntax when you want to put the result of determining the last year as a set into the rows.

Comment: Yes, it delivers the name of last year & month as output (sth like this: [Czas].[Czas].[Rok].&[2013].[Kwartał 2].[maj]). Then I use this measure as default value --> as parameter in the another dataset. As for me I got what I wanted. ;)